# How to use the index of group by element in the dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, plotly

I have created a mean of salaries group by college type. Now I want to use this data to plot the graphs [image]

```
y = df['Starting Median Salary']

# I want to use dataframe in this code using their index.
x = df['School Type']

# Use textposition='auto' for direct text
fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Bar(
            x=x, y=y,
            text=y,
            textposition='auto',
        )])

fig.show()
```

You can find the dataset and my output [enter link description here](https://www.kaggle.com/wsj/college-salaries)

Comment: change x to `college['Starting Median Salary']` and y to `college.index`

Comment: Do you want plot a Bar graph of the data you've shown in the picture i.e b/w school type vs salary?

Comment: Yes I want to plot a bar plot  mean values of salaries with school type

Comment: check the solution I've uploaded right now.

Comment: check the edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just needed to use inplace=True in the reset command. The graph worked [image]

````
df.reset_index(inplace = True)
df
y = df['Starting Median Salary']

x = df['School Type']

#Use textposition='auto' for direct text
fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Bar(
            x=x, y=y,
           text=y,
           textposition='auto',
        )])

fig.show()```
````

Answer (score 1):

use seaborn:

```
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.DataFrame({'school type':['Engineering','Ivy','arts','party','state'],'Salary':[59057,60475,45746,45715,44126]})

print(df)

sns.barplot(x='school type',y = 'Salary',data=df)
plt.show()
```

Output:

```
   school type  Salary
0  Engineering   59057
1          Ivy   60475
2         arts   45746
3        party   45715
4        state   44126
```

[image: Output image of Barplot]

**[EDIT]**

In your code, in next cell run this:

```
sns.barplot(x='School Type',y = 'Starting Median Salary',data=df)
plt.show()
```

And remove this below snippet from your code:

```
fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Bar(
            x=x, y=y,
            text=y,
            textposition='auto',
        )])

fig.show()
```

Comment: I don't want to hardcode it like this  {'school type':['Engineering','Ivy','arts','party','state'],'Salary':[59057,60475,45746,45715,44126]}.Rather  I want to use the groupby in plotly figure which i am getting

Comment: yes just inplace of -->sns.barplot(x='school type',y = 'Salary',data=df)<-- place  sns.barplot(x='School type',y = 'Starting Median Salary',data=df). in your code and remove the code you've written for plotting from your code.